# this.state.account and this.state.followers are not updated onMouseOver?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-state-management, react-bootstrap-table

When Bootstrap table rows are *hovered* the **twitter_account in Twitter state is updated**.But when passed as props for **TwitterChart class It is not updated**.

```
const twitterData = [
  {
    account: "marwilliamson",
    followers: 2610335,
  },
  {
    account: "BernieSanders",
    followers: 9254423,
  },
  {
    account: "Hickenlooper",
    followers: 144816,
  }
]
export {twitterData};

/////////

import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import {twitterData} from './twitter_data'

export const Twitter = () => {
  const data = useMemo(() => twitterData, [])
  const [twitter_account,settwitter_account] = useState('');
  const [twitter_followers,settwitter_followers] = useState(0);
   function onRowMouseOver(row){
    settwitter_account(row.account);
    settwitter_followers(row.followers);
    }
  const options = {
    onRowMouseOver: onRowMouseOver,
  };
  return (
    <div>
    <div className="twitter-followers">
    <div className="followers-header">
        <BootstrapTable data={ data } options={options}>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='account' dataFormat={CellFormatter} isKey={true} dataSort={ true } dataAlign='left' width='120' headerAlign='left' className="header">ACCOUNT</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='followers' dataSort={ true } width='120' dataAlign='center'  headerAlign='left' className="header">FOLLOWERS</TableHeaderColumn>
           
        </BootstrapTable>
    </div>
    </div>
 
    <TwitterBarChart account={twitter_account} followers={twitter_followers}/>
  
    </div>
  )
}

/////////

class TwitterBarChart extends React.Component {
 
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data : twitterData,
            account:props.account,
            followers:props.followers,
        }
    }
   render() {
   
      console.log(this.state.account);
      return(
   <div className="barchart-msg-container">
                <p className="barchart-message"><strong>{this.state.account}</strong> has <span>{this.state.followers}</span> followers on Twitter</p>
            </div> 

     )

}
```

> twitter_account , twitter_followers are not getting updated on props.

> console.log(this.state.account) //account value is not updating onMouseOver.

Comment: Where is the onMouseover event

Comment: @linchong onMouseover event is in the table collumn. react-bootstrap-table is used for the table.

Comment: <BootstrapTable data={data} onRowMouseOver={onRowMouseOver} />.           Console.log(twitter_account) is working on Twitter.js. But when passed as props to class TwitterChart.js it is not getting updated.??

Comment: Important parts are missing in your question. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after many references I got the answer.

should use componentWillRecieveProps(newprops){}

Thanks for contributing